# Prove the Limit Definition of a Pseudo-Inverse

Tags: limits, pseudoinverse

I spend lot of hours on this problem, but now I'm givin it up.

As you can read in the title, the problem is about proving on ***R*** (I mean the calculation program) that **the Moore-Penrose Pseudo-Inverse of this specific matrix**

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

can be calculate by limiting (as it is written on Wikipedia on that page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#Limit_relations).

Can someone help me? If it is possible also with some calculations on ***R***.

Thanks!

Comment: Formatting tips here:http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/321264.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thank you for the formatting tips!